# Editors for composing posts before posting on to math.SE

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

I like to use an editor to compose my Q&A's in an editor which can enable me to see a preview. I like to do this due to some non-technical reasons such as to avoid the hurry to click the submit button. I also would like to take a print out and read coolly before sending it to math.SE. So I request you to suggest me some editors of this sort.

Comment: What's wrong with the existing preview? If it's the slow update (5 second delay) then there is a patch in a prior thread here to enable instanteous update (like on MO).

Comment: @jasper : Is it possible to take a print out of what is shown in preview box alone without actually pressing the submit button ?

Comment: There was recently a similar question: [MathJax: better way to prepare a Math.StackExchange question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4735/mathjax-better-way-to-prepare-a-math-stackexchange-question/)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, I tried adding (mathjax) tag but it synonymizes to (tex).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found

http://www.latexeditor.org/

which is a freeware TeX and LaTeX editor for Windows.

The trick will be finding an offline tool that supports both Markdown and TeX at the same time.

I would recommend a programmers' editor like TextMate or Vi or EMacs with Markdown and Tex plugins... but those are distinctly ASCII based and wouldn't offer a GUI preview.